# What is the correct past tense of 이다?

Tags: tense

What is the correct past tense of 이다?

Is it 이었어요 or 였어요 or something else? If there one correct answer or does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

였다 follows a vowel, and 이었다 follows a consonant(batchim).

Examples:

> 그는 경찰이었다. (He was a policeman)
>
> 그는 아직 아기였다. (He was still a baby)

Answer (score 2):

I believe 이었다 is the more 'correct' form, but they are both correct, one is just a shortened form of the other.

The same thing happens with 되었다 and 됐다